# Working with Classes/Function in PHP - Very Confusing

Tags: php

First of all please read and dont downvote in a heartbeat.

Im sure there are thousends of examples on how to work with classes and such, but i still cant figure out how it works in php, and i would need some help as a newbie with my example that im trying to do, to really understand it.

i have this function

```
 class CaloriesOutput

    public function equationCaloriesMaleOutput(){
    $contentDto = new \ContentDto();

    $weight = $contentDto->getWeight();
    $height = $contentDto->getHeight();
    $age = $contentDto->getAge();

    $equationGainCaloriesMale = ((10 * $weight) + (6.25 * $height) + (5 * $age) + 5) + 250;
    $equationLoseCaloriesMale = ((10 * $weight) + (6.25 * $height) + (5 * $age) + 5) - 300;

    echo  '<br /> To Gain Weight you would need around: ' . $equationGainCaloriesMale . 'Calories';
    echo  '<br /> To Lose Weight you would need around: ' . $equationLoseCaloriesMale . 'Calories';
    echo  '<br /><h6>Note: No activity is beeing take into count. Please <a href="https://www.calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html">go here</a> for More information.</h6>';
}
```

And im my index.php

This is how im trying to call this.

```
                   try{
                        $caloriesOutPutMale = new CaloriesOutput();
                        $caloriesOutPutMale->equationCaloriesMaleOutput();

                    }catch (Exception $exception){
                        echo $exception->getMessage();
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['gender'])){
                        if ($_POST['gender'] == 1){


                        }else if ($_POST['gender'] == 2){
                            echo  '<br /> To Gain Weight you would need around: ' . $this->$caloriesOutPutMale . 'Calories';
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```

Where does my logic have a fault here ?

> K:\xxamp\htdocs\index.php:171 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in K:\xxamp\htdocs\index.php on line 171

Line 171 would be `$caloriesOutPutMale = new CaloriesOutput();`

Thank you in advance. Please help a newbie out :/

Comment: Please Highlight row 171 in your source code...

Comment: `$contentDto = new \ContentDto()` missing semicolon. Error should have indicated this "syntax error". As for OOP best practices... You might want to study some design/architectural patterns. Specifically MVC is something you might want to explore. I don't like HTML, let alone output, from a class.

Comment: Somehow it got deleted, its in my code, That is not the problem. You are right to i will edit.

Comment: You ask us not to read and quickly downvote, **however** you aren't practicing any of the suggestions in this site's help (for example, your title is vague and fairly useless).  Please review [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Then we assume its in the constructor of `ContentDto()`, As @StefanoBuora suggests, highlighting the line in question would help.

Comment: Are you copy/pasting this directly from your code? Or are you trying to reproduce it by hand?

Comment: @stefanoBuora I did in the main post

Comment: Well that is the line the exception bubbled up to. [Look at the whole trace](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php). Or comment out the try/catch block if you can't figure that out. The actual error is under that call.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? If so, to help other people who have encountered a similar problem, consider marking an answer which helped you as the accepted one, or leave your own answer if the answers provided did not help solve the problem. If provided answers did not help, please consider commenting on them to help clarify. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a syntax error inside of your class, if it is copied over exactly.

A quick overview of a Class in PHP is that it's a collection of related functions. You need to wrap all of the functions of your class inside of `{}`'s just as you would wrap the logic of a single function. So if you did the following, it should work:

```
class CaloriesOutput {
  public function equationCaloriesMaleOutput(){
    $contentDto = new \ContentDto();

    $weight = $contentDto->getWeight();
    $height = $contentDto->getHeight();
    $age = $contentDto->getAge();

    $equationGainCaloriesMale = ((10 * $weight) + (6.25 * $height) + (5 * $age) + 5) + 250;
    $equationLoseCaloriesMale = ((10 * $weight) + (6.25 * $height) + (5 * $age) + 5) - 300;

    echo  '<br /> To Gain Weight you would need around: ' . $equationGainCaloriesMale . 'Calories';
    echo  '<br /> To Lose Weight you would need around: ' . $equationLoseCaloriesMale . 'Calories';
    echo  '<br /><h6>Note: No activity is beeing take into count. Please <a href="https://www.calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html">go here</a> for More information.</h6>';
  }
}
```

As some commenters mentioned, this code doesn't follow OOP best practices. The idea behind OOP is that you can reuse the code for many different things, so very little should be hard-coded. This is outside of the scope of this question, however. Finally, this error could have been picked up by virtually any IDE, so it isn't exactly the best kind of question for Stack Overflow.